# initb fails for brew postgresql-upgrade-database

Tags: postgresql

I am using `brew postgresql-upgrade-database` to upgrade postgresql from 11.8 to 12 and migrate the data.  The process failed with the following output

```
Upgrading postgresql data from 11 to 12...
```

Stopping `postgresql@11`... (might take a while)
==> Successfully stopped `postgresql@11` (label: homebrew.mxcl.postgresql@11)
waiting for server to shut down.... done
server stopped
==> Moving postgresql data from /usr/local/var/postgres to /usr/local/var/postgres.old...
==> Creating database...
Error: Upgrading postgresql data from 11 to 12 failed!
==> Moving postgresql data back from /usr/local/var/postgres.old to /usr/local/var/postgres...
Error: Failure while executing; `/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/12.4/bin/initdb --lc-collate=en_US.UTF-8 --lc-ctype=en_US.UTF-8 --lc-messages=en_US.UTF-8 --lc-monetary=en_US.UTF-8 --lc-numeric=en_US.UTF-8 --lc-time=en_US.UTF-8 -E\ UTF8 /usr/local/var/postgres` exited with 1.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an [issue][1] using `brew postgresql-upgrade-database`.  I will update this answer when the issue is resolved.

As at July 21, 2021 this issue is still open.  My workaround is below:

**WARNING** this will wipe out your databases so they have to be reloaded or re-initialized.

```
brew uninstall --force postgresql
brew install postgresql@12
cd /usr/local/var/
rm -rf postgres
initdb /usr/local/var/postgres
```

When doing the `brew install` read the post install message and make sure that you have the correct paths etc in your `.zshrc` (or equivalent file e.g. .bashrc). If you do not have this set your path correctly, the `initdb` command may work.
[1]: http://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/issues/60686

Comment: Hey, @Obromios, were you able to fix the issue? I am having the same problem.

Comment: Unfortunately as May, 2022 still seeing this problem. A recent operating system upgrade broke my databases, even though I had `brew pin postgresql@12`.  Trying to look on the bright side, it is an opportunity to upgrade your databases by either a minor or major version.