# brew pin does not prevent upgrading of postgresql formula

Tags: postgresql, homebrew

I am trying to prevent my current version of `posgtgresql` being upgraded. Accordingly I did `brew pin postgresql@12`.  However I am finding that if I do

```
pg_ctl -D /usr/local/var/postgres -l /usr/local/var/postgres/server.log start
```

I get the following error message

```
        waiting for server to start.... stopped waiting
    pg_ctl: could not start server

Examine the log output.
```

Looking at the log output, the last lines are

```
2022-05-01 17:31:00.816 AEST [18650] FATAL:  database files are incompatible with server
2022-05-01 17:31:00.816 AEST [18650] DETAIL:  The data directory was initialized by PostgreSQL version 12, which is not compatible with this version 14.2.
```

so `postgresql` has been updated to version 14.2.

If I do `brew list --pinned` it shows

```
postgresql@10
postgresql@11
postgresql@12
```

so I am still have `postgresql@12` pinned. So why has the pinning not worked, and how do I restore `posgresql` to version 12?

I notice that if I do `brew services list` I see

```
postgresql    none           
postgresql@10 none           
postgresql@11 none           
postgresql@12 error  6 Chris ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.postgresql@12.plist
```

i.e. `postgresql@14` is not listed, so perhaps `postgresql` was upgraded in some other manner than using `brew`?  However, I certainly did not do explicit upgrade, so do not see how this could have happened.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In lieu of an answer to this question, the way I recover from this situation is explained in this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64867320/1299362).

In brief (**warning this destroys the databases**)

```
brew uninstall --force postgresql
brew install postgresql@12
cd /usr/local/var/
rm -rf postgres
initdb /usr/local/var/postgres
```

Trying to look on the bright side, it is an opportunity to upgrade your databases by either a minor or major version.